# URL está com Localização como abrir no Webview Android

Tags: android, webview

Pessoal no link url que coloquei no webview foi implementado localização. Assim que o usuário abre o site pelo chrome ou qualquer navegador aparece um dialog perguntando se ele permite usar a localização.

Mas no webview não aparece essa pop-up, tem como implementar isso, aparecer essa dialog dentro do app?

[image: Quando entro no site pelo navegador é esse dialog que aparece]

Comment: mas ele abre o referido local no webview que roda no tel?

Comment: @Armando ele abre o link normalmente no app, funciona normalmente. Só queria que aparece essa pop up também no app

Comment: problema que o webview é algo tipo um meta-browser, e esse controle vem do aparelho e do os instalado nele, aconselho no caso esse link caso você precise mesmo de mostrar esse popup via html: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Comment: caso contrario, voce pode criar algo para verificar se o app acessou o gps e depois de confirmado abrir a pagina

Answer (score 1):

Bom pessoal resolvi da seguinte forma, não sei se é a mais correta. Segue abaixo o código.

No método onCreate

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_site);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath());

    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    abrirPagina();
```

Criei duas classes

```
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        public  boolean overrideURLLoading (WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A subclasse WebChromeClient lida com chamadas relacionadas à UI
     */
    public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
                                                       final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
//dialog perguntando se o usuário permite ou não pegar sua localização
            dialog.setTitle("Acessar sua localização");
            dialog.setMessage("O aplicativo quer acessar sua localização. Você" +
                    " permite?");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Permitir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    callback.invoke(origin, true, true);
                    Log.i("localizacao", origin);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Negar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    callback.invoke(origin, false, true);
                    Log.i("localizacao", origin);
                }
            });
            dialog.create();
            dialog.show();

        }
    }
```

E o método `abrirPagina()`

```
private void abrirPagina() {
    try {
        WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();

        if (detecta.existeConexao()) {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            String url = "https://www.flaviodeoliveira.com.br";

            ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            ws.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
            ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            ws.setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); //5mb
            ws.setSupportZoom(false);
            ws.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            ws.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            ws.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            ws.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            ws.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

            webView.loadUrl(url);

        } else {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ws.setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
            Toast.makeText(this, "No momento você está sem conexão com a internet.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Executando o app, ele apresentará um `dialog` perguntando se permite ou nega a pegar a localização pelo browser dentro do webview. Caso ele permita, na segunda vez que ele executar o app não irá mais aparecer o `dialog` pois no `callback.invoke(origin, true, true);` deixei o último parâmetro como `true` para que ele memorize.

Bom não sei se é a melhor forma, porém pelo que eu li funcionou no app.